# How do I use a tax_query and a meta_query in wordpress succesfully?

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-query

This is the code I am using:

```
$results = array(
                'post_type' => 'score',
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'competitions',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $tax->slug,
                        'compare' => '='
                    )
                ),
                'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'numberposts'   => -1,
                        'post_type' => 'score',
                        'meta_key'     => 'horse_name',
                        'meta_value'   => $horsename,
                        'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    )
                )
           );

// query
$the_query = new WP_Query($results);
```

The problem is I can't work out how to make a Boolean AND expression so that both the taxonomy and the custom field should match before returning a post.

Answer (score 0):

I revised your code. check below code.

```
$results = array(
    'post_type'        => 'score',
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'tax_query'        => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'competitions',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $tax->slug,
            'compare'  => '='
        )
    ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'meta_key'   => 'horse_name',
            'meta_value' => $horsename,
            'compare'    => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);
// query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $results );
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to change anything with regard to making the expression a boolean AND. I need to select the posts based on the taxonomy term and on a custom field term.

Comment: I fix your code. you are passing `'numberposts'   => -1, and  'post_type' => 'score',` in meta. query that's wrong.

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesn't solve my problem that I need the AND combination of the taxonomy and the custom field

Comment: You can not add `AND` between `tax_query` and `meta_query` as per the current query this will display only those data that have tax slug you defined and meta value you pass.

Comment: Is there a way around this then?

Comment: if you have the correct value in database the this code should be work